# Render text as password using system password char in Windows Forms.NET

Tags: winforms, textbox, render, passwordbox

The Windows Forms `TextBox` control has two properties, `PasswordChar` and `UseSystemPasswordChar`, which control the obscuring of passwords typed into the `TextBox`.  I need to render the specified text onto a non-TextBox graphics surface the same way.

I can calculate the length of the specified string and create the equivalent text representation if we use the char from the PasswordChar property, but what about UseSystemPasswordChar? How do we retrieve the effective system password char?

Or maybe there is a flag or a ready-to-use .NET method or class we can use to render the specified text as password without doing all this work manually?

Comment: "render specified text" sounds pretty weird in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The default password character in windows is an astrisk unless visual styles are enabled, in which case it is a black circle.

You can check to see if visual styles are enabled via `Application.RenderWithVisualStyles`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761594(v=vs.85).aspx

Alternatively, you could create a textbox and simply read the value of PasswordChar, though this feels a little dirty.

```
 char passwordChar = (new TextBox(){UseSystemPasswordChar = true}).PasswordChar;
```

Under the hood this call is sending the `EM_GETPASSWORDCHAR` message to the windows api.

Comment: what if this setting will be changed in the future versions of OS? We need a good method to retrieve the current system password character.

Comment: There isn't a "system password character" per se, it's based on the underlying control in the Windows API (not sure of the behavior on Mono).  I've updated my answer with the dynamic way to retrieve the character.

Comment: I also tried to do the same:

    TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
    myTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    fPasswordCharEffective = (char)iGNativeMethods.SendMessage(myTextBox.Handle, NativeMethods.EM_GETPASSWORDCHAR, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    myTextBox.Dispose();

But it's very funny that the PasswordChar property returns the effective password char when UseSystemPasswordChar is True even if it was set to something else at design-time! I set it to "*", but when UseSystemPasswordChar is True, PasswordChar returns the black disk in my Win7!